# In Python, how can I calculate a set of values from a for loop and then plot those values using matlibplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have the user input an upper limit for a function calculation, then run a for loop to calculate.

However, my for loop does the correct calculation for a range of values, but matlibplot doesn't plot them.

```
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d = int(input("Enter your upper limit of degrees for sine function: "))

for i in range(0,d):
  y=m.sin(m.radians(i))
  print(i,y)

plt.plot(i,y)       
plt.show()
```

A graph appears but no line or plotted values when I expected a line.

Answer (score 1):

> matlibplot doesn't plot

```
plt.plot(i, y)
```

> I expected a [waveform].

You're offering scalars to `.plot()`, there.
Prefer to offer a pair of vectors if you'd like to see a waveform.

---

```
from math import radians, sin
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def get_points(d=180):
    for x in range(0, d):
        y = sin(radians(x))
        yield x, y

df = pd.DataFrame(get_points(), columns=['x', 'y'])
plt.plot(df.x, df.y)
plt.show()
```

[image: half-wave]